# Что означает слово "найферунг"?

Tags: семантика, заимствования

Уважаемые участники форума! Возможно мой вопрос имеет мало общего с русским языком, но, смею надеяться, здесь есть полиглоты. Что такое "найферунг"? Говорят, некое прилагательное из немецкого языка, либо похожего на немецкий. Интернет перевод не даёт. Дело в том, что этим словом был назван населённый пункт на территории РБ до ВОВ.

Answer (score 2):

Не полиглот))

Предположу, что это искаженное немецкое [Aneiferung](https://translate.google.co.uk/#view=home&op=translate&sl=de&tl=en&text=an%C2%ADei%C2%ADferung), в котором начальное *А* отбросили, и, скорее всего, стали произносить с ударением на последний слог.

Это не прилагательное, а существительное, образованное от глагола [aneifern](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/aneifern) (которое гугл переводит на русский как [подбодрить](https://translate.google.co.uk/#view=home&op=translate&sl=de&tl=ru&text=aneifern)) по стандартной для немецкого схеме - с помощью [*-ung*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ung#German) (см. Ordnung).

Таким образом, *Aneiferung* - это, то, что на английский я бы перевёл, как [encouragement](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=opera&biw=1709&bih=854&sxsrf=ALeKk00Oxyyz6CiuNbGragc8J5bDmwFolw%3A1587630111814&ei=H1ChXvmzMdLrgAb12LLYBg&q=encouragement+translate&oq=encouragement+tran&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgAMgIIADICCAAyBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeOgQIABBHOgQIIxAnOgUIABCRAjoECAAQQzoFCAAQgwE6BwgAEIMBEEM6CggAEIMBEBQQhwI6CQgAEEMQRhD_AToECAAQCjoHCAAQRhD5AVCJOVjmjAFg9pwBaABwAXgAgAFjiAGuCpIBAjE4mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab). С переводом подобных слов на русский есть некоторые сложности - желательно знать контекст, чтобы подобрать наиболее подходящий синоним из ряда *поощрение*, *стимул(ирование)*, *подбадривание*, *подзадоривание* и т.п. Но общий смысл, думаю, понятен.

Судя по гугло-результатам, сущ. *Aneiferung* - достаточно редкое, и помечено, как *южно-немецк., австрийск*.

Если раскопаете историю происхождения этой деревни - добавляйте сюда. Случай интересный.

Comment: В этом районе происходили столкновения с армией Напалеона, так же и разбегалась его армия через эти места. Думаю, некоторые осели, отсюда и название такое странное. Сейчас это деревня с рядовым названием "буда". Надеялся, узнав перевод, приблизиться к разгадкам истории.

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ. Может, так и было:голодных измученных солдат там поддержали и приютили, они дали своё название местности, где поселились. Правда, на другом форуме дали перевод "приближение". Ваш выглядит логичнее, если верно моё предположение.